# Where is the documentation for Opa's classic syntax?

Tags: opa

The [blog post introducing the new syntax](http://blog.opalang.org/2012/02/opa-090-new-syntax.html) said that the old MLish syntax would still be available and supported, and there's nothing in the changelog suggesting that it was ever gotten rid of, but I can't find any reference to it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see the old documentation here : http://doc.s3.opalang.org/

The new JS-like syntax has been introduced with version 0.9.0 as you can see in the [changelog](http://opalang.org/resources/changelog.xmlt).

Comment: The link to the old documentation is dead. We can still find it here, though: http://web.archive.org/web/20120902014800/http://doc.s3.opalang.org/